# Determining the mean center and standard distance of a dataset in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset called `mypoints` and I have created a polygon and plotted the points as below:

```
mypoints=read.csv("d:\\data\\venus.csv",header = T)
mypoints
minx=min(mypoints[,1])
maxx=max(mypoints[,1])
miny=min(mypoints[,2])
maxy=max(mypoints[,2])
mypolygon=cbind(c(minx,maxx,maxx,minx),c(miny,miny,maxy,maxy))
plot(mypoints)
polygon(mypolygon)
```

I now want to write a function that calculates both the mean center and standard distance for mypoints. I then need to plot the standard distance as a circle centered on the mean center of all points with the radius equal to the standard distance. Note that the last expression evaluated in a function becomes the return value, the result of invoking the function.

So far:

```
#I think this how I calculate the mean center for x and y:
x1=sum(mypoints[,1])/length(mypoints[,1])
y1=sum(mypoints[,2])/length(mypoints[,2])

#This is the formula I was shown for standard distance:
sd.mypoints=sqrt(sum(x1+y1)/n)

#This is the formula I was shown for creating the circle:
symbols(sd.mypoints[1],sd.mypoints[2],sd.mypoints$sd,add=T,inches=F)
#This is the error that I get when I run the circle formula:
```

> Error in sd.mypoints$sd : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

I have found it easier to find the Nearest Neighbor, do KDE, Ghat, and Fhat for this dataset than trying to figure this out. I am sure there is a easy solution for this but I just can't seem to get it. Third class in R and it has been a lot of fun up to this point.

Comment: The problem seems to be that `sd.mypoints` is not a data.frame, hence `sd.mypoints$sd` doesn't exist, and the error telling you that you can not subset an atomic vector. Replace `sd.mypoints$sd` for `sd.mypoints` in your last `symbol` expression

Comment: That worked for not giving me an error but still not seeing the actual plot so I think the problem is before that. Cheers.

Comment: Can you post your data?

Comment: How do I do that? It is a .csv file with 924 rows. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You have the line

```
symbols(sd.mypoints[1],sd.mypoints[2],sd.mypoints$sd,add=T,inches=F)
```

in your code. As said in the comments, `sd.mypoint` is not a data.frame, so subsetting it with  sd.mypoint$sd` causes the error you see.

From the documentation of `symbols`, which you can access with `?symbols` you'll see that for circles the `circles` argument is mandatory, so the function can differentiate what sort of figure is drawing.

#### EDIT:

Also, please notice that you are using `x` and `y` points to `symbols` different to the ones you already calculated. So you need to replace that line with:

```
symbols(x1, y1,circles = sd.mypoints,add=T,inches=F)
```

Notice the use of `x1` and `y1`. I can see the plot now.

Comment: That worked for not giving me an error but still not seeing the actual plot so I think the problem is before that with calculating the mean center and standard distance. Cheers.

Comment: I can see the plot but not the circle that was supposedly drawn, Cheers,